# How to deal with roaming heroes

Tags: warhammer-total-war

The enemy has random heroes wandering through my lands, trying to hamper my armies. But I cannot attack them with my army. How do I deal with these super annoying heroes? It seems similar to the agents in Total War: Shogun 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroes in TW: Warhammer act a bit different to how agents work in previous TW installments, in the sense that they can be part of an army, where they provide various advantages to the army itself, **and** fight on the battlefield, *or* they can work as solitary agents, which is more in line with previous TW games.

Heroes are any of the following units:

**The Empire**

- Captain of the Empire - Melee
- Warrior Priest – Melee/Caster
- Witch Hunter – Ranged
- Celestial Wizard – Caster (Lore of Heavens)
- Light Wizard – Caster (Lore of Light)
- Bright Wizard – Caster (Lore of Fire)

**Vampire Counts**
-   Banshee – Melee

- Necromancer – Caster (Lore of Vampires)
- Vampire – Melee/Caster (Lore of Death)
- Wight King – Melee

**Dwarves**

- Master Engineer – Ranged
- Thane - Melee
- Runesmith

You can take them out using your armies if, and only if, the hostile hero is part of an army - your armies cannot attack sole heroes.

Alternately, you can attack them with your own heroes. Note that if your own hero is part of an army, you need to select the hero, rather than the lord/army stack as a whole in order to target the hostile heroes. Note that this will cause the hero to leave the army (though they can rejoin it later, assuming they survive their mission).

See also:

http://wiki.totalwar.com/w/How_Lords_Work

and

http://wiki.totalwar.com/w/How_Heroes_Work